# Use JavaScript string operations to cut out exact text

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, phantomjs

I'm trying to cut out some text from a scraped site and not sure what functions or library's I can use to make this easier:

example of code I run from PhantomJS:

```
var latest_release = page.evaluate(function () {
                // everything inside this function is executed inside our
                // headless browser, not PhantomJS.
                var links = $('[class="interesting"]');
                var releases = {};
                for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
                    releases[links[i].innerHTML] = links[i].getAttribute("href");
                }

                // its important to take note that page.evaluate needs
                // to return simple object, meaning DOM elements won't work.
                return JSON.stringify(releases);
            });
```

Class `interesting` has what I need, surrounded by new lines and tabs and whatnot.

here it is:

```
{"\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting\n\t\t\t\n\t\t":null,"\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting\n\t\t\t\n\t\t":null,"\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting\n\t\t\t\n\t\t":null}
```

I tried `string.slice("\n");` and nothing happened, I really want a effective way to be able to cut out strings like this, based on its relationship to those `\n'`'s and `\t`'s

By the way this was my split code:

```
var x = latest_release.split('\n');
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var interesting = {
        "\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting1\n\t\t\t\n\t\t":null,
        "\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting2\n\t\t\t\n\t\t":null,
        "\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting3\n\t\t\t\n\t\t":null
    }

    found = new Array();
    for(x in interesting) {
        found[found.length] = x.match(/\w+/g);
    }
    alert(found);
```

Comment: This was perfect! I'm going to look into `regular expressions` a lot now, I need to understand exactly how `(/\w+/g)` can transform the text so much. Pretty amazing. Thanks :)

Comment: The regex as is will return an array of words if the interesting text has spaces in it. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Its a simple case of stripping out all whitespace. A job that regexes do beautifully.

```
var s = "  \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tI Am Interesting\n\t\t \t \n\t\t";
s = s.replace(/[\r\t\n]+/g, ''); // remove all non space whitespace
s = s.replace(/^\s+/, ''); // remove all space from the front
s = s.replace(/\s+$/, ''); // remove all space at the end :)
console.log(s);
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with "\\n" as pattern? your \n may be understood as plain string rather than special character

Comment: yeah, your right about the reason it didn't work, \\n works like a charm. however \\t will only remove one tab and not the others.

Comment: `var x = latest_release.split('\\n'+'\\t');` this makes this :`",\t\t,\t\t\tI_Am_Interesting,\t\t,\t":null,` still have issue getting that middle part though, it only seems to go so far

Comment: you can use a Regex for more complicated split. Here is a website that helps building javascript regex, with some tutorials and live test : http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 0):

```
new_string = string.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "");
```

Comment: string.replace() can only find and replace the first condition they meet.

Comment: Yes I agree, we should use regular expressions here. I think that solution provided by Amith George will work

Comment: @SomethVictory You can use the global flag to replace all matches in a string - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace .